# Can anybody explain why the JS regex expression fails in this case?

Tags: javascript, regex

Running this code in JSFiddle results in a "no problem" for "l" but a "problem" for "m", even though both variables appear to be the same format.
https://jsfiddle.net/zj8mg518/26/

```
    var errString;
    var l = "JLF5J-383Z3-QQKWR-JEN3T-39NUT-3";
    var m = "12345-12345-12345-12345-A";

    function Check_License_Key_Format(license) {
        var regexLicense = new RegExp("^([A-za-z0-9]{5}[-]){5}[A-Za-z0-9]$");
        return regexLicense.test(license);
    }

    if (Check_License_Key_Format(l) == false)
        errString = "problem";
    else
        errString = "no problem";            
    alert(errString);

      if (Check_License_Key_Format(m) == false)
        errString = "problem";
    else
        errString = "no problem";
    alert(errString);
```

Comment: Note that the `[-]` in your regex is just a long way to write `-`.

Comment: Also note that `A-z` is not the same as `A-Z`, the first part of your regex is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's read your regex, shall we?

"Five groups of (five letters/numbers followed by a hyphen) followed by a letter/number"

I only count 4 groups in the `m` variable. So it fails.

---

Separately, you have `A-z` rather than `A-Z` near the beginning. It should be `A-Z`.

Comment: Very nicely, concisely put!